# File encoding in WebStorm, utf-8 with BOM

Tags: webstorm

by default WebStorm creates file in utf-8 encoding, but without BOM. How can i add BOM label in my files?

Answer (score 1):

According to the Unicode specification:

> Use of BOM is neither required nor recommended for UTF-8 ([Chapter 2.6](http://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode5.0.0/ch02.pdf))

There is a [related request](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-63850) and [forum discussion](http://devnet.jetbrains.net/thread/290334), feel free to comment there.

Comment: @Wachburn Just curious -- what browser is that and can I have example of such file (file with few lines should be enough).

Comment: @LazyOne chrome, firefox, IE. Opera display it correctly. Link to download http://filestore.com.ua/?d=F916158D9

Comment: Just add proper `meta` tag and it will become OK in all of them: `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />` (for HTML5 it's much shorter: `<meta charset="UTF-8">`) Alternatively -- set this on web server level (so the charset is sent together with the response header -- helps speeding up parsing document a bit: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/18504/character-set-not-specified-in-http-headers-error ). **P.S.** It displayed gibberish in all browsers for me since my default system code page is not Cyrillic.